# Is it possible to know the serial number of the block of input data on which map function is currently working?

Tags: hadoop

I am a novice in Hadoop and here I have the following questions:

(1) As I can understand, the original input file is split into several blocks and distributed over the network. Does a map function always execute on a block in its entirety? Could there be more than one map functions executing on data in a single block?

(2) Is there any way that it can be learned, from within the map function, which section of the original input text the mapper is currently working on? I would like to get something like a serial number, for instance, for each block starting from the first block of the input text.

(3) Is it possible to make the splits of the input text in such a way that each block has a predefined word count? If possible then how?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. As I can understand, the original input file is split into several blocks and distributed over the network. Does a map function always execute on a block in its entirety? Could there be more than one map functions executing on data in a single block?

   No. A block(split to be precise) gets processed by only one mapper.
2. Is there any way that it can be learned, from within the map function, which section of the original input text the mapper is currently working on? I would like to get something like a serial number, for instance, for each block starting from the first block of the input text.

   You can get some valuable info, like **the file containing split's data, the position of the first byte in the file to process. etc**, with the help of **[FileSplit](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileSplit.html#getStart%28%29)** class. You might find it helpful.
3. Is it possible to make the splits of the input text in such a way that each block has a predefined word count? If possible then how?

   You can do that by extending [**FileInputFormat**](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) class. To begin with you could do this :
   In your getSplits() method maintain a counter. Now, as you read the file line by line keep on tokenizing them. Collect each token and increase the counter by 1. Once the counter reaches the desired value, emit the data read upto this point as one split. Reset the counter and start with the second split.

HTH

Comment: OP has posted comments to your answer in my answer (FYI)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you define a small max split size you can actually have multiple mappers processing a single HDFS block (say 32mb max split for a 128 MB block size - you'll get 4 mappers working on the same HDFS block). With the standard input formats, you'll typically never see two or more mappers processing the same part of the block (the same records).
2. [`MapContext.getInputSplit()`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MapContext.html#getInputSplit%28%29) can usually be cast to a [`FileSplit`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileSplit.html) and then you have the Path, offset and length of the file being / block being processed).
3. If your input files are true text flies, then you can use the method suggested by Tariq, but note this is highly inefficient for larger data sources as the Job Client has to process each input file to discover the split locations (so you end up reading each file twice). If you really only want each mapper to process a set number of words, you could run a job to re-format the text files into sequence files (or another format), and write the records down to disk with a fixed number of words per file (using Multiple outputs to get a file per number of words, but this again is inefficient). Maybe if you shared the use case as for why you want a fixed number of words, we can better understand your needs and come up with alternatives

Comment: @Tariq I have a situation in which I am required to identify a portion (sub-string) of a given text (string of words) having certain properties. There may be more than one such desired sub-strings. I need to report the off-sets of each of them from the beginning of the text. For example, if the text is "To be, or not to be, that is the question" and the desired sub-string is "that is the" then the offset of this sub-string in the original string is 7.

Comment: My original text can be huge, therefore, I am trying to use map-reduce to implement it, where each map function searches for the sub-strings from the portion of the text it has been assigned to. I am facing a few problems while doing so. One of them is to find out the offset of the sub-strings identified by each map function in the original text. For this reason i am thinking assigning each map function with a text which has equal number of words in them.

Comment: Also if I know the serial number of the text that has been assigned to the map function, then I can generate the offset my multiplying the serial number with the number of words and then adding the offset in the portion of the text assigned to the current map function.

Comment: The above comments are directed towards both Tariq and Chris. Both the answers were informative for me. I could not share the exact use case, as Chris had asked for in his answer, so I tried to include a little detail of what I actually want to do. An answer from any of you will be very helpful.

Comment: Do your input files have single sentences per line, or can a sentence wrap multiple lines (as this is going to make your algorithm more complicated)

Comment: My input files can have multiple sentences per line. The text may have paragraphs which ends with a newline. Additionally, each split should have a minimum number of words, so I can not have splits based on newline. I am not sure if the problem that I am trying to solve fits seamlessly into the map-reduce framework, I am giving it a try.

Comment: Sounds like you want to modify the TextInputFormat and associated RecordReader / LineReader to look for the period character rather than  a new line when delimiting (such that you get complete sentences to your mapper), and this should then be possible. You must send complete sentences though, otherwise with a fixed word count you can't easily handle where the phrase you're looking for breaks over multiple input records or lines.